# Need a quick way of removing partial duplicates from a log

Tags: bash, logging

I'm using a bash script to grep out some lines from a log file. The basic format of this log file is:

> field1: value1, field2=value2, field3=value3,
>   field4=value4,value5,value6, field5=value7

Sometimes there will be lines in which field1: value1 is identical, but some of the other information is either the same or different. I'd like to filter those lines out, so that I only grep out the first instance of anything that has the same "field1: value1" tuple.

I'd prefer a nice command-line one-liner if you can find something especially simple. I definitely want to keep it in the bash script. This is on linux, so we've got all the command-line tools available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '!arr[$1]++ { print }' LOGFILE
```

The `awk` program uses an array to keep a count of the number of times a particular 'field1: value1` string is seen, but only prints the incoming line the first time.